# Is there more paypal api to call after capture?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have very little paypal experience, but am developing some mobile app backend using Flask.

I am using the v2 checkout API in order to pay a fixed amount in order for the user to have something, currently using sandbox accounts and sandbox client IDs.

I am calling the `POST v2/checkout/orders` API endpoint to create an order, including the following in the payload

```
...
"application_context": {
    "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/paypal/approve",
    "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/paypal/cancelled"
}
...
```

That return_url is called with `token=<ORDER_ID>&PayerID=<PAYER_ID>` parameters after the user approves the payment, and it calls the `POST v2/checkout/orders/<ORDER_ID>/capture` API endpoint to capture the order.

After checking in my paypal developer dashboard, I have noted that the sandbox buyer account has its Paypal balance deduced of the amount, but the sandbox store owner (business account) doesn't have its Paypal balance added that amount.

After checking the notifications in the paypal developer dashboard, I have noted two notifications, one for the payer, and one for the payee:

- sb-rsvvn879105@business.example.com | Money is waiting for you | 31 Mar 2020 04:21:21
- sb-6dd8n877465@personal.example.com | Receipt for Your Payment to John Doe's Test Store | 31 Mar 2020 04:21:21

And those are what I can see from the API calls menu in the paypal developer dashboard, both with OK status

- /v2/checkout/orders/4JP666895R973750K/capture | 10c6183daabff | 31 Mar 2020 04:20:32
- /v2/checkout/orders | 57dbafbf30234 | 31 Mar 2020 04:18:36

So, my question would be, is there another API endpoint that needs to be called in order for the business account to get his money (and add it to its Paypal balance) or is the process of purchasing complete and the business account just has his money somewhere else?

**Additional information:**

- I am not using the default sandbox application credentials
- I am using the default business account (created along with the default sandbox application) with my custom sandbox application
- I am using the default personnal account (created along with the default sandbox application) with my custom sandbox application
- The default sandbox application and my custom sandbox application have the same settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Money is waiting for you

It looks like the payment is pending , log into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com with sb-rsvvn879105@business.example.com within 30 days, and you can accept the payment (otherwise it will be automatically refunded)

If it's pending for currency reasons (e.g. you sent a payment in a currency the account did not hold), then once you open that new currency balance, payments won't be pending in the future

Comment: and it was the currency, and logging in into the business account allows me to accept the payments, the accounts were created as US accounts and used USD as currency, and my code is using EUR currency